# If Salvatore has achieved the test and Carmela has achieved the test,then Benedetto also has achieved the test.But Salvatore didn't achieve the test.

Tags: logic

> If Salvatore has achieved the test and Carmela has achieved the
>   test,then Benedetto also has achieved the test.But Salvatore didn't
>   achieve the test.So:
>
> A)Benedetto didn't achieve the test.
>
> B)Benedetto could have achieved the test.
>
> C)Benedetto or Carmela didn't achieve the test.
>
> D)Benedetto didn't achieve the test and Carmela has achieved the test.
>
> E)if also Carmela didn't achieve the test,Benedetto didn't achieve the
>   test.

(The correct answer is **C**,but I would like to see the correct way to apprach this problem with a clear reasoning.)

**My effort**

Abstracting the problem I define $S,C,B$ as the events where respectively Salvatore,Carmela and Benedetto achieved the test, then I have that $$S \land C \to B $$

Now I am not able to draw conclusions if I have the case where $\lnot S \land C $.

Going backwards I can see that $$\lnot B \to \lnot(S \land C )=\lnot S \land \lnot C $$ (which is true since both $S,C$ are) which would give me the answer **E** (which is wrong).I guess that's because I am going from the other direction,that is given that I have $\lnot S$ I am saying that $\lnot(S \land C ) \to \lnot B$ which isn't necessarily true.

> **Question** I am a beginner in math logic so I am a bit confused on how to draw correctly the conclusions in this problem. Any
>   help,advice,insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ex falso sequitur quodlibet*. That is, if your assumption is false (and your assumption $S \land C $ is assumed false), than anything follows.

Comment: And of course this implies that $B$ is the correct answer.

Comment: This is not helpfull at all if you just say that this imples $B$and thus it is the correct answer,please show me your reasoning.

Comment: My book gives as answer $C$ not $B$.

Comment: If Salvatore didn't pass the test, then anything could  have happened, so every answer *could* be correct, but the only one which *is surely* correct is $B$, because it doesn't provide any definite information.

Comment: *If Salvatore has achieved the test* **and** *Carmela has achieved the test,then Benedetto also has achieved the test. But Salvatore didn't achieve the test.*
Are you sure of this?

Comment: Yes I see it now,I guess it's a typo in my book.Thanks for sharing your reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is B, not E.  Your hypotheses are $(S \wedge C) \to B, \lnot S$  Having $S$ be false makes the antecedent of the implication false, so the implication is true regardless of the truth of $C$ or $B$.